# my FB LOGIN ignores permissions

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

When approving application, it only ask for some default access to public profile + friendlist but  i have far more permissions selected in my php code, but probably i dont know how to pass them to login, cuz i never seen it passed to anything  in any tutorials 
this is some sample of my code:

```
$permissions = 'user_photos,read_stream,user_photo_video_tags,friends_photo_video_tags,user_actions.news,publish_actions,publish_stream,publish_checkins,manage_pages,photo_upload';

$fb = new Facebook(array('appId'=>$appId, 'secret'=>$secret)); 
$fb->setFileUploadSupport(true);
// etc, etc... but $permissions variable is only used when
 if (fb->getUser()) //fail <br>
else $fbloginurl = $fb->getLoginUrl(array('redirect-uri'=>$returnurl,  
                                          'scope'=>$permissions)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i did change in my form view
(i have checkbox, when checkboxed -> fires popup with my FB-app / login ) 

`onClick="FB.login()"`  


to 
`onClick="FB.login(function(response) { if (response.authResponse) { }},{ scope: 'publish_actions, user_photos,photo_upload' })`

It works like this, but it isnt very nice or best solution i guess... and i hoped for solution through php file , so im still open to new answers

[here is link to my form view code](http://pastebin.com/PMCdCvsi)

Answer (score 0):

You should ask for the additional permissions when you have the public permissions ready. I did the same thing in asp.net a while ago. So, when user has accepted the default permissions you make another permissions request. That should do it!